# What property on the item presenter of an ItemsControl is associated with its place in the list?

Tags: wpf, xaml, itemscontrol

What I am trying to do is have a ItemsControl where I can specify which of its items are visible. I created a DataTemplate for the ItemContainer, but I do not know the name of the element I am binding to, or the "index" which would be a numeric representation of which item it is in the list.

```
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Charts}" 
                                  x:Name="ItemsControl">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Visibility>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource }">
                                            <Binding ElementName=""
                                                     Path=""/>
                                            <Binding Path="WhichAreVisible" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Visibility>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

**Edit**

As per Clemen's suggestion I created an index property on the object in the list and set the binding to that, but when I put a breakpoint in my converter I see the value for that binding is DependancyProperty.UnsetValue the data context is that object, there is a property on the object, why doesn't it see the property?

```
                  <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding Charts}" 
                                  x:Name="ItemsControl">
                        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                            <ItemContainerTemplate >
                                <ContentPresenter Content="{Binding}">
                                    <ContentPresenter.Visibility>
                                        <MultiBinding Converter="{StaticResource Converter}">
                                            <Binding Path="Index"/>
                                            <Binding Path="WhichAreVisible" />
                                        </MultiBinding>
                                    </ContentPresenter.Visibility>
                                </ContentPresenter>
                            </ItemContainerTemplate>
                        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
                    </ItemsControl>
```

Comment: Better bind the ItemsSource property to a CollectionViewSource with a filter.

Comment: @Clemens It would be a better solution if we could do it that way, but we can't.

Comment: @Clemens Do you know the name and path?

Comment: You could probably bind the Visibility of the ContentPresenter in an ItemContainerStyle to a property in the data item class.

Comment: @Clemens Thank you for that suggestion, I followed your advice there, but it seems like the binding is not picking up the property on the object in the list (as per updated question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may bind the `Visibility` property of the ContentPresenter (that contains an item) to an appropriate property in the data item class, in a Style that is assigned to the ItemsControl's `ItemContainerStyle` property.

Given a DataContext like

```
DataContext = new object[]
{
    new { Text = "Item 1", IsVisible = true },
    new { Text = "Item 2", IsVisible = false },
    new { Text = "Item 3", IsVisible = true },
    new { Text = "Item 4", IsVisible = false },
    new { Text = "Item 5", IsVisible = true },
};
```

the following ItemsControl would only display the first, third and last item:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <BooleanToVisibilityConverter x:Key="BooleanToVisibilityConverter"/>
</Window.Resources>
...
<ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
    <ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
        <Style TargetType="ContentPresenter">
            <Setter Property="Visibility"
                Value="{Binding IsVisible,
                        Converter={StaticResource BooleanToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
        </Style>
    </ItemsControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Text}"/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
</ItemsControl>
```